# Limit of a sequence including roots

Tags: sequences-and-series

I want to calculate the following limit:

$\displaystyle \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{\sqrt{4n-1}-\sqrt{4n-2}}{\frac{1}{n}+\sqrt{n+2}-\sqrt{n}}$

I guess the limit is $\frac18$, but how can i calculate it? If i try to simplify the expression anyway i always get $\frac00$ ... Maybe i can solve it with l'hospitals rule assuming that it is a continuous function. But i don't want to use this rule.

Do you have another idea?

Comment: If you have a limit including roots you can normally expand and use the binomial formula ... i tried but failed

Comment: multiply by $\frac{\sqrt{4n-1} + \sqrt{4n-2}}{\sqrt{4n-1} + \sqrt{4n-2}}$ and use the identity $a^2 - b^2 = (a-b)(a+b)$.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try and report later. I already tried to use this identity, but i just used the denominator for the multiplication.

Answer (score 1):

$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} $ $(\sqrt{4n-1}+\sqrt{4n-2})(\frac{1}{n}+\sqrt{n+2}-\sqrt{n})$ $=0+\frac{2\times(\sqrt{4n-1}+\sqrt{4n-2})}{\sqrt{n+2} +\sqrt{n}}$ $=\frac{2\times(2+2)}{2}=4$ So $\frac{1}{4}.$